# PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Tags: php

"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in .... on line 62"

Line 62-65:

```
$scCon = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
if(!$scCon) {
$scsuccess=1;
}
```

Help! How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe you have to remove the `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to specify the requirement for a reference when the function is defined, not when you call the function.

So amend the function call to

```
fsockopen("$scip", $scport, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

If the function has been defined as requiring a reference it will turn your call time parameters into references and if it does not require a reference it will not

Comment: I keep forgetting to do that lol. Accepted it. By the way, what if it has been defined requiring a reference? I'm getting that parameters error now

Answer (score 0):

Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

```
$scCon = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, $errno, &$errstr, 30);
if(false === $scCon) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the leading & in $errno and $errstr.

```
$scCon = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
```

will become

```
$scCon = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

As of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out :)